# Mysql: Sum calculated columns

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

Hey there!
I do have a question regarding SQL. Is there a way to sum the red marked values? So e.g. AAG will not be seperated into 2 columns but aggregated into one. So AAG 2 and AAG 4 become one single row with AAG 6

Help is appreciated :)
Have a nice day

Comment: Remove the second part of your `GROUP BY`.  Just group by `t.TEILEID`.

Comment: Hey, yes, I tried sum, but it shows 12 for AAG, which is obviously wrong. It should be 6. I really have no clue why it is doing that. Any idea? Also, I can't remove the second part of my Group by as it would throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would do it:

You need to use `SUM()`

```
SELECT t.TEILEID
    , SUM(t.BESTAND - t.RESERVIERT)
FROM   TEILE t
      INNER JOIN AUFTRAGSPOSDS a ON a.TEILEID = t.TEILEID
WHERE  a.AUFTRNR = 15
GROUP BY t.TEILEID;
```

After reading your comment I think you need this:

```
SELECT t.TEILEID
    , SUM(t.BESTAND - t.RESERVIERT)
FROM   TEILE t
WHERE  t.TEILEID IN
                (SELECT a.TEILEID
                FROM   AUFTRAGSPOSDS a
                WHERE  a.AUFTRNR = 15)
GROUP BY t.TEILEID;
```

Comment: Hey, yes, I tried that, but it shows 12 for AAG, which is obviously wrong. It should be 6. I really have no clue why it is doing that. Any idea?

Comment: @user2669261 in the table AUFTRAGSPOSDS you may have two records corresponding to each record in TEILE

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible:

```
select t.TEILEID, SUM(t.BESTAND - t.RESERVIERT) from ...
GROUP BY t.TEILEID
```

Comment: Hey, yes, I tried that, but it shows 12 for AAG, which is obviously wrong. It should be 6. I really have no clue why it is doing that. Any idea?